# SslStream.ReadAsync never calls InnerStream.ReadAsync

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I'm not sure if I'm missing something or there is indeed a design flaw in SslStream (and, probably, other stream classes which can wrap inner streams).

Consider this pseudo-code:

```
MyStream
{
  Task<int> ReadAsync()
  { ... }
}

...

{
  MyStream my = new MyStream();
  SslStream ssl = new SslStream(my);
  ssl.ReadAsync(...);
}
```

Although the one could expect that SslStream.ReadAsync will eventually call MyStream.ReadAsync, it won't. Instead, it would call MyStream.BeginRead (if it was defined). If MyStream.BeginRead is not defined, the behavior will be hard to predict (it will depend on from which class MyStream is derived and so on).

In short, to make async/await methods of SslStream work as expected, the one needs to implement BeginXXX/EndXXX (non-async/await methods) of an inner stream class.

BeginXXX/EndXXX pattern is much more complex for development than async/await pattern (and for me, this was the reason of introducing async/await - to make async programming easier). But the requirement to still develop BeginXXX/EndXXX methods defeats the purpose of async/await.

Moreover, the one needs to know the internal implementation of SslStream class (because it could directly call InnerStream.ReadAsync if implemented differently). I mean the public signature of SslStream does not clearly provide me with enough info on whether I should implement ReadAsync or BeginRead in my inner stream class.

For that, I need to use trial and error approach or examine the source code of SslStream (and its Stream parent as SslStream inherits ReadAsync from basic Stream class). This does not seem to be a reliable and straight-forward way to write code.

Is current implementation of async/await methods like ReadAsync in SslStream/Stream classes for a reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Task` implements `IAsyncResult` so you should be able to get away with

```
return ReadAsync(...);
```

as the implementation of `BeginRead`. Maybe it's a little more complicated, for example you need to hook up the callback as a continuation to that task. But you can reuse the code.

Btw, you broke the Stream API contract in that `BeginRead` did something different than `ReadAsync`. Strictly speaking this is your fault, not a framework problem.

> I mean the public signature of SslStream does not clearly provide me with enough info on whether I should implement ReadAsync or BeginRead in my inner stream class.

Not necessary to know. When you inherit from a class you inherit *all* obligations that this class has. You must implement everything because that's what you promise to users of that class. Obvious example: If you derive from `IEnumerator` you can't just implement `MoveNext` but leave out `Current` and expect callers to work.

Comment: "When you inherit from a class you inherit all obligations that this class has." I understand that I have to do this. I know how to fix my issue (with implementing all methods including BeginXXX methods).
I just thought that async/await was added to get rid of dealing with BeginXXX but it doesn't help that. That's what I thought of design flaw.
Design flaw of requiring me to implement something which was superseded with new functionality. But your statement that I can reuse my async code with returning Task as IAsyncResult helps! Thanks.

Comment: Right. It's usually a good goal to minimize complexity and async stuff increases complexity. So you could consider simply going synchronous and many issues just go away.

Comment: @Alex But it does help you with that, every time you use the APIs. The only thing that doesn't avoid the old async pattern is while implementing new streams (e.g.) - that still means you concentrate the "old, complex" stuff in a tiny method, while everything else is nicely `await`-y. The default `ReadAsync` calls `BeginRead`, so you can easily use `await` on streams that were written before `Task`/`await` support. It's just that there's no way to get rid of `BeginRead`, because the internal implementations of other async streams *are* still using it.

Comment: Still, I'm in trouble. Calling my ReadAsync from my BeginRead (where my ReadAsync internally calls base.ReadAsync) obviously causes stack overflow by calling my BeginRead in base.ReadAsync internals. Seems the only way is to provide independent implementations of XXXAsync and BeginXXX methods.

Comment: @Alex you need one implementation but need to override all methods.

Comment: @usr thanks again for your help. I was actually overriding them all but I made a stupid bug: in ReadAsync I called BeginRead (which called ReadAsync recursively) instead of base.BeginRead. Now it's working fine.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, `Stream` in particular is a bit messed up, because it existed long before `async`/`await`. For example, the default implementation of `ReadAsync` will actually do a blocking read on a thread pool thread.

I recommend that you override `ReadAsync` as a regular TAP method, and also `BeginRead`/`EndRead` as APM wrappers for that TAP method. The [MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873178(v=vs.110).aspx#TapToApm) have the best pattern for this (properly handling `callback` and `state`), except I prefer to tweak them a bit so any exceptions from `EndRead` are not wrapped in an `AggregateException`:

```
public static IAsyncResult ToBegin<T>(
    Task<T> task, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
{
  var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<T>(state);
  task.ContinueWith(t =>
  {
    if (t.IsFaulted) tcs.TrySetException(t.Exception.InnerExceptions)
    else if (t.IsCanceled) tcs.TrySetCanceled();
    else tcs.TrySetResult(t.Result);

    if (callback != null) callback(tcs.Task);
  }, TaskScheduler.Default);
  return tcs.Task;
}

public static T ToEnd<T>(IAsyncResult result)
{
  // Original MSDN code uses Task<T>.Result
  return ((Task<T>)result).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

Comment: Is it safe not to provide a `CancellationToken.None` to the continuation? I'm always a bit fuzzy on stuff like that... If `task` has a `CancellationToken`, cancelling it would prevent the continutaion, right? Which *might* cause (tiny?) issues? Oh, and I love the trick with `GetAwaiter` :D Does it preserve the original call stack correctly?

Comment: In this case, the continuation runs regardless of the task's ending state. The TCS task will end up with a different `CancellationToken` than the `ReadAsync` task, but that usually doesn't matter. Yes, `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` does preserve the original call stack - it's essentially what the `async` state machine is doing. A bit ugly, but it works. :)

Comment: Oh, that's ugly - but very useful for frameworks. Do you think it makes sense to use this approach for other cases when you'd usually have to wrap the unwrapped exception before throwing? Or is it *too* hacky? :D

Comment: I find myself using it everywhere now. Console main methods, etc.

Answer (score 2):

`ReadAsync` is just a helper wrapper around the deeper asynchronous APIs.

If you want to override the asynchronous behaviour, the best bet is to override `BeginRead` and `EndRead` instead - the default implementation of `ReadAsync` will build up the tasks on top of those (and the other `BeginRead`s will call `BeginRead`s of the underlying stream).

This is just because `ReadAsync` was added later - and in fact, on some platforms, they're not available yet. But in the end, expecting that `ReadAsync` will work as an overload is quite similar to expecting that it will automagically use the `Read` you've overloaded - they don't really fit.

But do not worry - this doesn't make it any harder to use the `Task`-based APIs! `Task` itself implements `IAsyncResult`. So while overriding the `BeginRead` method, just let it return `ReadAsync` :)

Simplified sample implementation:

```
class MyStream : Stream
{
    public override async Task<int> ReadAsync
      (byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        const string str = "Hi there!\r\n";

        await Task.Delay(1000);

        return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str, 0, str.Length, buffer, offset);
    }

    public override IAsyncResult BeginRead
      (byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
    {
        return ReadAsync(buffer, offset, count).ContinueWith(t => callback(t));
    }

    public override int EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        // Stolen from Stephen. Nicer than rethrowing the inner exception manually :)
        return ((Task<int>)asyncResult).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
}
```

Obviously, it's very easy to make this into a base class - allowing you to only override the `ReadAsync` method in children. If that's not an option, you can manage the functionality in extension methods (doesn't look all that important with the simplified code, but you probably want to have some checks and error handling in the real code; and more importantly, you really want to handle the `state` - for my test case, implementing it is unnecessary, but it's just one more thing that violates the API).

As @usr pointed out, the point you missed is that it's *your* responsibility to make sure your stream behaves consistently. It's like if you only overrode the `==` operator but not `Equals` or `GetHashCode` - the resulting inconsistencies are your fault, because you're supposed to ensure consistency. On the other hand, if you only overrode `BeginRead`, it would work fine, because the default implementation of `ReadAsync` calls `BeginRead` - the code *has* to remain backwards compatible. But for exactly the same reason, it can't work the same the other way around.

**EDIT:**

Okay, I've written something that should work fine even for passing a `state`
(now updated for both `Task` and `Task<T>`):

```
static class Extensions
{
    struct Unit { }

    public static IAsyncResult Apmize<T>(this Task<T> @this, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
    {
        return @this.ApmizeInternal<T>(callback, state);
    }

    public static IAsyncResult Apmize(this Task @this, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
    {
        return @this.ApmizeInternal<Unit>(callback, state);
    }

    private static IAsyncResult ApmizeInternal<T>(this Task @this, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
    {
        if (@this.AsyncState == state)
            return @this.ContinueWith(t => callback(t));

        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<T>(state);

        @this.ContinueWith
            (
                t =>
                {
                    if (t.IsFaulted) tcs.TrySetException(t.Exception.InnerExceptions);
                    else if (t.IsCanceled) tcs.TrySetCanceled();
                    else
                    {
                        if (t is Task<T>) 
                        {
                            tcs.TrySetResult(((Task<T>)t).Result);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            tcs.TrySetResult(default(T));
                        }
                    }

                    if (callback != null) callback(tcs.Task);
                },
                CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.Default
            );

        return tcs.Task;
    }
}
```

The usage would be something like this:

```
public override IAsyncResult BeginRead
  (byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
{
    return ReadAsync(buffer, offset, count).Apmize(callback, state);
}

public override IAsyncResult BeginWrite(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
{
    return WriteAsync(buffer, offset, count).Apmize(callback, state);
}
```

It's a bit longer, but it's just one reusable extension method. And it handles the state properly :)

Comment: Thanks. Do I need separate implementation of this extension method for BeginWrite? Because WriteAsync is returning void and there is no Task<void> in C#.

Comment: @Alex Yeah, you've got basically two options - either make another version that works on `Task`, or use something like `Task<object>`, or better, `Task<Unit>` (where `Unit` is some "empty" type; no need to expose it, always return just `Task` or `IAsyncResult`). You'll need that for the `TaskCompletionSource` anyway, so you can just make a simple method overload that doesn't do anything but call the `Task<Unit>` overload.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not getting how to convert Task (returned by Stream.WriteAsync) to Task<something> (be it 'object' or custom-defined type)..

Comment: @Alex Right, of course, you can't. I didn't mean you should do that. You'd have to wrap the inner task in another task. But you don't really *need* that. You're only exposing `IAsyncResult` - both `Task` and `Task<T>` implement that. To keep things DRY, you can change the helper methods to be a bit more flexible - let me add an example...

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't compile. And I can't understand how it can work because Apmize<T> wants Task<T> on input, not Task. In my opinion, "@this.ApmizeInternal<Unit>(callback, state)" means that Unit will be passed to ApmizeInternal but the method itself must still be called for an instance of Task<T> type, not Task. And that's what makes the compiler complain.

Comment: @Alex You must have copied something wrong. There's two overloads for `Apmize<T>` - one that takes `Task<T>` and another that takes `Task`. `ApmizeInternal` takes `Task`, not `Task<T>`.

Comment: Oh, indeed, you're right. I didn't initially notice you removed <T> from 'this Task<T> @this' in ApmizeInternal declaration. Now it's all fine, thanks!

Comment: The code crashes on Xamarin.iOS. The caller passes callback=null so that 'if (@this.AsyncState == state) @this.ContinueWith(t => callback(t))' leads to NullReferenceException. I'm not sure what that section of ApmizeInternal should do when callback is not set..

Comment: @Alex Good question. If the caller doesn't care about the asynchronous callback, I guess you can drop the `ContinueWith` entirely - just do something like `return callback == null ? @this : @this.ContinueWith(t => callback(t));`. It doesn't necessarily mean you lsoe the asynchronous support - you can keep checking `IAsyncResult.IsCompleted` or just use `IAsyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle` to register your own callback, for example.

Comment: But shouldn't I simply let the rest of the method execute instead of returning @this? ? I mean that stuff from 'var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<T>(state);' and below.

Comment: @Alex Well, it's been a long time... but I don't think so. That's only there for the case where the `state` doesn't match - we basically have to unwrap the actual task that went on and call the callback. If there's no state and no callback, you can just use the input task as `IAsyncResult` directly.